# Powering a massive addressable LED project

Tags: power-supply, led, led-matrix

So a two part question. I've built large scale LED projects in the past, but for the next one it would be massive (a black hole disc with a diameter of 54 ft), and addressable LEDs on the top and bottom. Ideally, they would be WS2812B string LEDs so that I could control them with video using DMX controller. At the current size of the LED strings (14ft, 50 LEDs and 3 inches apart from each one), I estimate it would be 15,120 LEDs on the top and bottom, so 30,240 total.

For the size, I don't need LEDs that close together to produce a coherent effect I think. Is there another way people do projects of this size without using something like these? https://www.amazon.ca/Rextin%C2%AE-WS2811-Digital-Addressable-Waterproof/dp/B01AU6UG70/ref=sr_1_14?crid=2BZM04MO85064&keywords=btf+ws2812b+string&qid=1658861330&sprefix=%2Caps%2C206&sr=8-14
Obviously the wattage would be insane for this. I've done 3000 LEDs, and had to boost power with a new power supply every 150 LEDs, in different outlets. Even with multiple power injections, how would I not blow every fuse imaginable?

I've seen many buildings and large scale LED displays in China for example, how is this typically done?

Here are some visual renders of the prototype:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That will be a 8kW heater and require serious ventilation.

Comment: Depending on brightness and how many LEDs you plan to have on at once (hint: you probably don't want to run at max brightness!) thats a few kilowatts.   My stove, HVAC, and EV charger all use more power than that, and I'm on a normal residential supply.  You'd spec out your power requirements and have an electrician wire an appropriate breaker, or work backwards from the breaker you have and limit your power accordingly.

Comment: @bobflux true, LEDs shouldn't typically give off heat palpable heat, but that many might contribute

Comment: @user1850479 Thanks! True, I don't plan to run this white at all, so hopefully it will keep it well under the max load. I think at 60mA per LED, this project would likely be just over 1800A, plus a ceiling of 20-25% more for surge protection? So if I'm not mistaken, wouldn't that be around 9 kilowatts?

Comment: Yes that many LEDs will give off sigificant heat, but they also would need to be spread over quite a large area. 9kW spread over a 54ft diameter disc is not that much.

Comment: For 9kW you probably want a 50-63A 240V supply circuit, but those aren't that difficult to find connections for, though building a regulation system for that would be non-trivial.

Comment: 60mA means every LED at full brightness, which for RGB doesn't make a lot of sense. I would plan for maybe half that per LED, give or take. You might also want to measure the actual current as I believe some of these chip revisions use different current amounts.

Comment: If the power supply is in the center of the black hole, it can distribute power through all the radial lines, I guess there are about 120 per side, 240 total, so using 1800A total that's 7.5A per branch. 10m of 2.5mm2 copper wire is 70 mOhm. Current makes a roundtrip, so 140 mOhm. That may be doable.